# BJT saturation region problem

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, saturation

I have a graph and a definition like below:

[image]

> Saturation is the state of a BJT in which the collector current has
> reached a maximum and is independent of the base current.

Assume that \$V_{BE}=1V\$, \$I_{B1}=5.10^{-6}A\$ and \$V_{CE}=0.6V\$, if I maintain the \$V_{CE}\$ to be constant and change the value of \$I_B\$, why I can't make the \$I_C\$ jump up to some where like \$I_{B2}\$ line according to the definition above?

---

This is common emitter configuration.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry, that's my typo error, I will fix it now. But what is the contradiction?

Comment: @Andyaka so is the collector current still controllable by base current in reality?

Comment: The question is still inconsistent. Changing Ib without changing Vbe is not possible with properly working BJTs. To avoid confusion you should draw a schematic which shows the places of the voltages and currents  of your curve diagram.

Comment: @user287001 I mean Vce. Such a lot of typo error :(

Comment: There is still "VBB".

Comment: @CL. The Vbb=1V means that Vbe is forward bias.

Comment: \$V_{BE}\$ cannot be 1V. It can't be more than 0.7V without damaging the device, unless it's a beast of a transistor. It's \$V_{CE}\$ that can take on any value. I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @Becker If you are able to hold Vce to a fixed value of more than several volts (by applying a voltage source across the collector and emitter, for example) then the NPN BJT will not be in saturation. It may not survive well, if it heats up too much. But it won't be in saturation. Saturation is when the BC junction AND the BE junction are both forward-biased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're interpreting the graph correctly. There are some conditions *implied* by the graph. First, the independent variable (the X axis) is \$V_{CE}\$, which suggests that *you* provide \$V_{CE}\$ by directly applying a potential difference between the collector and emitter. This means there's no collector resistor or emitter resistor, or any other components in those places, just a voltage source between collector and emitter. This would be the setup used to determine the characteristics the the transistor as shown in the graph. This does not mean you must do this in an actual application, just that these were the test conditions used to establish the behaviour of the device.

Second, the dependent (Y) axis is collector current \$I_C\$, and is not under your control in this experiment. It's the transistor that will decide what current flows, not you. The author of this graph will simply have placed an ammeter in that current path (between the voltage source I mentioned earlier, and collector), and used it to determine what collector current flows as he varies \$V_{CE}\$.

Thirdly, \$I_B\$ is under the author's control, but it's kept constant while \$V_{CE}\$ is varied. The entire process of varying \$V_{CE}\$ and plotting the consequent \$I_C\$ is repeated several times, once for each plot, each time with a different value chosen for \$I_B\$. The manner in which you set \$I_B\$ to a constant value, while you plot \$I_C\$ vs. \$V_{CE}\$, is some kind of current source.

This whole setup is simple, and easy to simulate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGjV4B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the plot of a DC sweep simulation, where I've set \$I_B = 1mA\$, and I sweep \$0V \le V_{CE} \le 2V\$:

[image]

Notice that I've not specified \$V_{BE}\$ anywhere, and this is because it's almost never up to us to decide this value. When the base-emitter junction (a P-N junction, just like a silicon diode) is sinking current from some source, it's effectively a silicon diode, and will develop its own potential difference in the vicinity of 0.7V. The exact value is decided by the transistor itself. \$V_{BE}\$ is almost never imposed externally upon the transistor, and can never exceed 0.7V. Any more than that, and damage can occur.

Perhaps the most meaningful interpretation of this graph (at least to me) is as follows. In the active region, the curve is pretty straight. It is slightly sloped, even though that slope is barely discernible. This is a graph of current through a thing vs. voltage across the thing, and if that thing was a resistor, the slope of that graph would be its resistance, in ohms.

This is no different; essentially, the slope of the active "linear" region is directly related to the effective resistance of the collector-emitter path, for some given \$I_B\$. Technically, the rise-over-run slope is is the reciprocal of resistance, conductance, but in the parlance of transistors we call it "admittance". Probably because the straight lines of I/V graphs for ohmic components pass through the origin. A transistor is not ohmic, and the straight sections in the active region of your graph clearly all miss the origin by a mile.

Answer (score 2):

"Saturation is the state of a BJT in which collector current has reached a maximum and is independent of the base current".

I think that statement is referring to a situation where there is a resistor in the collector circuit. In that situation, increasing IB increases the collector current which increases the voltage drop across the collector resistor until the collector bottoms out (saturates). There is now the maximum voltage drop across the collector resistor which limits the collector current. The collector current cannot (nominally) increase any further even if IB were to increase further.

Those graphs are representative of transistor operation without a collector resistor.